# Where Can I write a custom code to perform some action based on test result, after all the convo file has been executed in Botium?

Tags: npm, automation, chatbot

> Suppose, I need to send mail after test suite execution including the test report, where can i write code to implement it in botium?

Answer (score 0):

Best option for adding such custom processing is to call Botium from a command line script (Botium Box or Botium Bindings or Botium CLI), and do this processing after running the Botium part.

There is a blog article about this topic in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/37584901/Schedule+Test+Runs+and+Send+Email+Notification)

Comment: Cant we do in botium script it self as we can add custom assertion in botium.?

Comment: or can I override the before and after hook of the script, because i need to do other task also instead of only sending an email

Comment: It is possible to develop your own logic hooks for BotiumScript (See https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24477705/Developing+Custom+Asserters), and Botium CLI in the newest build helps in setting up boilerplate projects for your own custom asserters and logic hooks. But BotiumScript is meant to be used for test case scripting only, not for test result processing, keep that in mind. Test results should be processed outside of Botium.

Comment: Okay..So Can i write post test suite result in mocha.js file where afterall() method is called? I need to override mocha file?
I think this way I can write post test suite logic as we write in aftersuite() method in selenium testng